# python flask and sqlalchemy error

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

i have this api developed in flask :

https://gist.github.com/scaltro/ca5a4a6256ff34a4e4163afacc95c6e0

when i execute this get on api :

```
/api/search?query=dsadsads&offset=0&limit=15&sort=recommended&search_id=1519341673454
```

return this errror :

https://gist.github.com/scaltro/374b4303e275e17475eb0b488aa4bb64

the moddels database is this :

https://gist.github.com/scaltro/37ab7d6180e88d1ae23b55142d186c39

i lose all night, i dont know where is the problem, return this error only when i use query search in get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `search_query` column in your database is an integer instead of the `string` you expect it to be. You'll either need to manually change that or simply recreate the database